# Can you think of a test which could make my program give wrong answers?

Tags: c, testing, data-structures

I am trying to solve this problem

http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=2014

I've got my solution working on the provided test. When I submit my solution I get wrong answer on the 11th test. So, could you please think about such an input which can make my program give wrong answers?

P.S. the problem is not time or memory shortage. The time of execution is 0.015s, and the memory used is 214 KB. I guess the test is quite short with reasonable numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct letter
{
    int change;     // amount of money spent or gained
    int date;       // packed date, I will never need the actual date, I will just need which date is earlier (smaller), and which is later (greater)
    int sign : 1;       // minus one for plus, zero for minus
    int seen : 1;       // minus one for seen, zero otherwise
} Letter;

int packDate(int, int, int, int);       // we will not need to know the date, just their relation to each other
void printLetter(Letter *);         // for debugging, not implemented
void getTime(int *, int *, int *, int *);   // read time from input
void selectionSort(Letter *, int);      // sort the letters by date, to get them in chronological order
void letterCopy(Letter *, Letter *, int);   // copy one array of letters to another
long long check(Letter *, int);         // evaluate the debt
int binSearch(int, Letter *, int);      // find the index of letter with given date

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    getchar();
    Letter *pletters = (Letter *)malloc(sizeof(Letter) * n);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {               // read letters
        char sign = getchar();
        pletters[i].sign = sign == '+' ? 1 : 0;
        scanf("%i", &pletters[i].change);
        getchar();
        int dd, MM, hh, mm;
        getTime(&dd, &MM, &hh, &mm);
        pletters[i].date = packDate(dd, MM, hh, mm);
        pletters[i].seen = 0;
    }                           // the letters are read
    Letter *plSorted = (Letter *)malloc(sizeof(Letter) * n);
    letterCopy(pletters, plSorted, n);          // make a copy of the letters array
    selectionSort(plSorted, n);             // sort copy, to get in historical order
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {               // evaluate each letter in original order
        int si = binSearch(pletters[i].date, plSorted, n);  // find the position of this letter in historical order
        plSorted[si].seen = 1;                  // mark it in historical order as seen
        printf("%li\n", check(plSorted, n));            // evaluate debt, based on all seen letters, and print it
    }
    return 0;
}

int binSearch(int d, Letter *l, int n)
{
    int mid;
    int low = 0;
    int high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (d < l[mid].date) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else if (d > l[mid].date){
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

long long check(Letter *s, int n)
{
    int i;
    long long cash, debt;
    cash = debt = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (s[i].seen) {
            if (s[i].sign) {
                cash += s[i].change;        // if letter states +, then add amount to Zhenya's cash
            } else {
                cash -= s[i].change;        // if he has money, he spends money from his cash
                debt += cash < 0 ? cash : 0;    // if he rans out of money, he will use credit card
                cash = cash < 0 ? 0 : cash; // if he used credit card, his cash is empty
            }
        }
    }
    return debt;
}

void letterCopy(Letter *s, Letter *d, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        d[i] = s[i];
    }
}

void selectionSort(Letter *l, int n)
{
    int i, j, min, mi;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        min = INT_MAX;
        mi = i;
        for (j = i; j < n; ++j) {
            if (l[j].date < min) {
                min = l[j].date;
                mi = j;
            }
        }
        Letter t = l[i];
        l[i] = l[mi];
        l[mi] = t;
    }
}

void getTwoDigits(int *);

void getTime(int *dd, int *MM, int *hh, int *mm)
{
    getTwoDigits(dd);
    getTwoDigits(MM);
    getTwoDigits(hh);
    getTwoDigits(mm);
}

void getTwoDigits(int *n)
{
    *n = 0;
    *n += (getchar() - '0') * 10;
    *n += getchar() - '0';
    getchar();
}

int packDate(int dd, int MM, int hh, int mm)
{
    mm += MM * 31 * 12 * 60 + dd * 12 * 60 + hh * 60;
    return mm;
}
```

The code works fine on provided test, and on the test I found in the discussion section. I think I could try to generate all the tests for a specific `n`, then write a script to go over all of them, and then manually check all the answers. Before I start this, can anyone come up with a test or with an idea how to do testing the most fast and efficient way?

Comment: I would think that the input from the 11th test might be a good starting point...

Comment: @twalberg I believe it's not available on this type of sites..

Comment: I would have though `while (low <= high)` is suspect in a binary chop. It's best to set `high` out of range, not within.

Comment: 1) Post the 11th test 2) Time values not checked for range. 3) `mm` in packed data may be out of `int` range.  4) iffy consumption of separators. 5) `while (low <= high) {` exit condition is suspect.

Comment: the 11th test input is not available, I would not post the question provided with the input. I didn't check time values for range bacause the input will also be correct and I won't need time, packDate function packs time and date in such way that it only keeps their position relative to each other, but i will think more about this, maybe there are some of time values that overlap after packing. I'll check for mm overflow. The reading part of the program works fine, maybe it's iffy, but that's not the reason for failure. binSearch works fine

Comment: no, I don't think time values will ever overlap, provided the input is correct

Comment: the largest time possible is 293820, and 2 ^ 32 / 2 (unsigned int, 32 bit) = 2147483648, if the size of int is 16 bit, then my program gives WA on values greater than 32768, but on provided test the first time is greater than 223200, therefore this is not where the problem is

Comment: maybe you have any ideas how could I get the test from the site. I tried some triks like: if ( n < 50000) n / 0; or malloc(1024 * n); First one would cause zero division, and changing the value after n or n I could figure out what the input is like. But they seem to have protection against that, no condition could cause zero division, i tried to write just n/ 0; and nothing happened, they removed this from code. Maybe if I work on more advanced condition system I could make the zero division

Comment: the second one would increase the memory usage by KB, but I guess I don't quite understand how the memory works, the result doesn't seem to be reasonable

Comment: also I tried if (n < 50000) printf("%i\n", 6666); this would make the program fail on the first test instead of 11th in case n is less than certain number. I tried this couple of times, but everytime it led me to different result

Answer (score 1):

Yes I can think of a lot of tests, for example in the beginning of the program type `aasdas` and press enter, there you go ... your program will do crazy things.

The reason is that you ignore `scanf()`'s return value, that's simply wrong, you must check that it succeeded, otherwise you will read from an uninitialized variable which of course causes a lot of problems.

So every `scanf()` requires a

```
if (scanf("%i", &n) != 1)
    doSomething_n_isUninitialized_Do_Not_useItsValue();
```

Comment: The input is always right formated, it is always in the form specified in the input section, the point is to find the numbers on which the algorithm fails to output right answers

Comment: @sasha199568 that is not a reason to write such an unsafe code, you don't know what could happen once you try to access the value of an uninitialized variable it could call a function or something, don't ever ignore that kind of thing.

Comment: usually I don't, but i would recieve wrong answer on test No 1, instead of 11 if that was the problem, also first line is guaranteed to be an int from 1 to 100000

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are 24 hours in a day, not 12